# Sharepoint 2010 (multi) lookup field xslt to show quantity of related items

Tags: xslt, sharepoint-2010

I would like to show in lookup column quantity of related by lookup items. I need template xslt definition. By default multi lookup shows large list of connected items.

Comment: Can you throw up some sample input XML and the desired output? Hard to understand your question.